# How to use multiple form in one view in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am new in django.I created two models.

```
class article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   disc = models.TextField()
   posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   cat = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class category(models.Model):
   cat_id = models.ForeignKey(article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   cate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to create a form template where user select category in drop down list and then write title, disc etc and submit form.when form is submit the data should save in article model and the selected category also save in cat field in article model.

What can i do ? please give me proper and easy way to do this.

Comment: did you read the django docs about working with forms? It should be pretty easy. So try it and see if any problems comes

Comment: try first yourself, if you hit any specific problems, post the question with the code you tried. SO isn't for letting others write your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your models.py :

```
   class article(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
       disc = models.TextField()
       cat = models.ForeignKey(category, verbose_name="Category")
       posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
       updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class category(models.Model):
       cate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Make a migrations to apply this modifications.

I think you just have to understand the relation between article and category. An article can only have one category. And a category can have many articles.
So the article model must have a foreign key for category. Not a foreign key in category for article.